# Finding text from file and assigning to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to find a text from file and assign it to a variable. I used `grep` with regex option to find a text. I need the output to get assigned to a variable so that I can use the output wherever I need. Filename: wgettesting.html

```
cat wgettesting.html
productvale:productvalues,productinfo:productinformation,product_group_type,value:product_genderledger,productcategories:smallcategories
```

Command I used in a script:

```
gl=grep -o --perl-regexp "(?<=product_group_type,value:product_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" wgettesting.html
echo $gl
```

When I run the script, I got: `-o: command not found` for the above command.

I also tried like:

```
gl=cat wgettesting.html|grep -o --perl-regexp ""(?<=product_group_type,value:product_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+"
echo $gl
```

For the above, I received: `wgettesting.html: command not found`

My intended output has to be:

```
genderledger
```

Someone guide me on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to put the `grep` command within `$()`,

```
$ gl=$(grep -o --perl-regexp "(?<=product_group_type,value:product_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" wgettesting.html)
$ echo $gl
genderledger
```

Commands should be enclosed within `$()` while assigning it's output to a variable.

Comment: I could not see the output getting printed. I used like this: `gl=$(grep -o --perl-regexp "(?<=product_group_type,value:product_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" wgettesting.html)
echo $gl` - I got empty output

Comment: post the output of `grep -o --perl-regexp "(?<=product_group_type,value:product_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" wgettesting.html`

Comment: when I run `grep -o --perl-regexp "(?<=product_group_type,value:product_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" wgettesting.html` I did not find output echoed. But I tried writing the output to a file and it has worked. I used: `grep -o --perl-regexp "(?<=product_group_type,value:product_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" wgettesting.html > producinfo` cat productinfo `genderledger`

Comment: I could not figureout why output is not getting printed in command line but could be written to a file

Comment: Which os are you running?

Comment: Linux Machine - RedHat OS

Comment: did you get any output after running `grep -op "(?<=product_group_type,value:product_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" wgettesting.html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62072/discussion-between-user3624000-and-avinash-raj).